# Unable to pass -p argument to .NET app when using dotnet run

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild

I am trying to pass a command line argument `-p` to my .NET Core app using `dotnet run`: `dotnet run -p /Users/user/Pictures`. However, when I do so, I get an error message like the one below. It looks like `dotnet run` is trying to open a project folder instead of passing this argument to my app. I can pass other things, like `-q`, to my app just fine.

How do I pass `-p` to my app when using `dotnet run`?

The error is this:

```
$ dotnet run -p /Users/user/Pictures

MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
Switch: /Users/user/Pictures
For switch syntax, type "MSBuild -help"
The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.
```

I'm trying to write a .NET app with switches like this:

```
Usage: du [-s] [-p] [-b] "path"

Summarize disk usage of the set of FILES, recursively for directories.
You MUST specify one of the parameters, -s, -p, or -b
-s      Run in single threaded mode
-p      Run in parallel mode (uses all available processors)
-b      Run in both parallel and single threaded mode.Runs parallel followed by sequential mode
```

Comment: Sounds like a typo. What command exactly are you trying to run?

Comment: updated with command and what it does.
It is not a typo.
I am trying to run it in Jetbrains Rider Terminal.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do here. `-p` is a `dotnet run` parameter, and it's also a `du` parameter? Do you want `/Users/user/Pictures` passed to `dotnet run` or to the application being run?

Answer (score 7):

You need to use `--` to tell `dotnet run` that you're done passing it arguments and that the rest should be passed to the app being run. `-p` is a short switch for `dotnet run --project`, which is used to specify the project file (e.g., .csproj file) to build and run. Your `-p` is specific to your app.

```
dotnet run -- -p /Users/user/Pictures
```

Comment: This was the solution. Thank you, new to C#.

Comment: Glad this was able to help. Consider [voting up or "accepting" this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).